# MDX subquery possibilities

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have the following MDX query:

```
 WITH 

member measures.uqname as 
    [D DATE].[DATE_YEAR_MONTH].currentmember.uniquename

member measures.monthnum as 
    left(right([D DATE].[DATE_YEAR_MONTH].currentmember.uniquename,3),2)

member measures.yearnum as 
    left(right([D DATE].[DATE_YEAR_MONTH].currentmember.uniquename,7),4)

member measures.quarter as
    "Q" + ltrim(rtrim(str(int(measures.monthnum/3))))

member measures.quartermember as
    "[D DATE].[DATE_YEAR_QUARTER].[DATE YYYYQQ].&["" + measures.yearnum + ""-"" + measures.quarter + ""]"


MEMBER MEASURES.TONNAGES_LL
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM
                            (
                                    (
                                        STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    
                                        [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1031]
                                    ),
                                    [Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]
                            ) * 
                            [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM
                    (   [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1031],
                        [Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]
                    ) * 
                    [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.BEDRIJFSOPBRENGSTEN
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1048]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1048],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END

MEMBER MEASURES.OMZET_OPSLAG_VERHUUR
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1073]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1073],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.EBIDTA
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1047]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1047],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END


MEMBER MEASURES.FINANCIELE_OPBRENGSTEN_EX_DIV
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1212]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1212],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.FINANCIELE_KOSTEN
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1214]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1214],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.COURANTE_CASHFLOW
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1046]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1046],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.CASHFLOW_VR_BELASTING
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1045]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1045],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.AFSCHRIJVINGEN
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1240]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1240],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.WAARDEVERMINDERINGEN
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1261]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1261],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.VOORZIENINGEN
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1265]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1265],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_10
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1044]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1044],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.DIVIDENDEN
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1236]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1236],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.UITZ_RESULTAAT
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1228]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1228],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.UITZ_OPBRENGST
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1229]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1229],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.UITZ_KOST
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1233]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1233],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.TE_BESTEMMEN_RESULTAAT
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((STRTOMEMBER(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1043]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1043],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")  
       END  

MEMBER MEASURES.TONNAGES_LL_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1031]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1031],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.BEDRIJFSOPBRENGSTEN_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1048]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1048],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.OMZET_OPSLAG_VERHUUR_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1073]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1073],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.EBIDTA_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1047]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1047],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.FINANCIELE_OPBRENGSTEN_EX_DIV_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1212]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1212],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.FINANCIELE_KOSTEN_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1214]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1214],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END
MEMBER MEASURES.COURANTE_CASHFLOW_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1046]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1046],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.CASHFLOW_VR_BELASTING_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1045]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1045],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.AFSCHRIJVINGEN_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1240]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1240],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END      
MEMBER MEASURES.WAARDEVERMINDERINGEN_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1261]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1261],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.VOORZIENINGEN_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1265]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1265],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_LY_00
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1044]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1044],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")    
       END  
MEMBER MEASURES.DIVIDENDEN_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1236]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1236],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END      
MEMBER MEASURES.UITZ_RESULTAAT_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1228]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1228],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END      
MEMBER MEASURES.UITZ_OPBRENGST_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1229]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1229],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END      
MEMBER MEASURES.UITZ_KOST_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1233]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1233],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END      
MEMBER MEASURES.TE_BESTEMMEN_RESULTAAT_LY
    AS CASE [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP REPORTING PERIOD")
         WHEN "Q" THEN SUM((strtomember(measures.quartermember),    [D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1043]),[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
         ELSE SUM([D ACCOUNTSCHEDULE].[ACCSCHED PARENTKEY].&[1043],[Measures].[QMAP_GL_AMOUNT YTD-1]) * [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("COMP PCT APPLIED")
       END      

MEMBER MEASURES.EBIDTA_D_01
    AS MEASURES.EBIDTA - MEASURES.EBIDTA_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.FINANCIAL_INCOME_D_02
    AS  MEASURES.FINANCIELE_OPBRENGSTEN_EX_DIV - MEASURES.FINANCIELE_OPBRENGSTEN_EX_DIV_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.FINANCIAL_CHARGES_D_03
AS MEASURES.FINANCIELE_KOSTEN - MEASURES.FINANCIELE_KOSTEN_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.EXTRAO_INCOME_D_04
AS MEASURES.UITZ_OPBRENGST - MEASURES.UITZ_OPBRENGST_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.EXTRAO_CHARGES_D_05
AS MEASURES.UITZ_KOST - MEASURES.UITZ_KOST_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.DIVIDENDS_D_06
AS MEASURES.DIVIDENDEN - MEASURES.DIVIDENDEN_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.WRITE_DOWNS_D_07
AS MEASURES.WAARDEVERMINDERINGEN - MEASURES.WAARDEVERMINDERINGEN_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.DEPRECIATIONS_D_08
AS MEASURES.AFSCHRIJVINGEN - MEASURES.AFSCHRIJVINGEN_LY

MEMBER MEASURES.PROVISION_D_09
AS MEASURES.VOORZIENINGEN - MEASURES.VOORZIENINGEN_LY


SELECT
 [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CHILDREN ON columns,
 {
        MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_LY_00,
        MEASURES.EBIDTA_D_01,
        MEASURES.FINANCIAL_INCOME_D_02,
        MEASURES.FINANCIAL_CHARGES_D_03,
        MEASURES.EXTRAO_INCOME_D_04,
        MEASURES.EXTRAO_CHARGES_D_05,
        MEASURES.DIVIDENDS_D_06,
        MEASURES.WRITE_DOWNS_D_07,
        MEASURES.DEPRECIATIONS_D_08,
        MEASURES.PROVISION_D_09,
        MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_10
    } ON ROWS
FROM Fin
where ([D DATE].[DATE YYYYMM].&[201407],[D COMPANY].[COMP GROUP 2].&[DRY BULK])
```

#### The output of the query

[image: screenshot output]

Now I want the sum for each of those rows:
So I want the sum of RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_LY_00, EBIDTA_D_01,...

Is this possible with an MDX subquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using reporting-services, why don't you just sum them in the report?

Comment: Reporting-services can't handle with a variable amount of columns. I need to ouput the data with only the row values and 1 column with the measure values(totals).  I can't use the sum function in the report itself. Because the field output of this query is the following: http://i.imgur.com/a8RibX2.jpg

Comment: If the sum of each row is the value for the "All" member of your `[D COMPANY].[D COMPANY]` attribute, then just replace `[D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CHILDREN ON columns` by `[D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].Members ON columns`.

Comment: That is not possible because all the values are measures that are calculated above in the query. So it's unpossible to use the "all" member of  the [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY] attribute

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a further measure which sums the other measures? (sorry this is not tested)

```
MEMBER MEASURES.x
AS 
     MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_LY_00 +
     MEASURES.EBIDTA_D_01 +
     MEASURES.FINANCIAL_INCOME_D_02 +
     MEASURES.FINANCIAL_CHARGES_D_03 +
     MEASURES.EXTRAO_INCOME_D_04 +
     MEASURES.EXTRAO_CHARGES_D_05 +
     MEASURES.DIVIDENDS_D_06 +
     MEASURES.WRITE_DOWNS_D_07 +
     MEASURES.DEPRECIATIONS_D_08 +
     MEASURES.PROVISION_D_09 +
     MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_10


SELECT
 [D COMPANY].[D COMPANY].CHILDREN ON columns,
 {
        MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_LY_00,
        MEASURES.EBIDTA_D_01,
        MEASURES.FINANCIAL_INCOME_D_02,
        MEASURES.FINANCIAL_CHARGES_D_03,
        MEASURES.EXTRAO_INCOME_D_04,
        MEASURES.EXTRAO_CHARGES_D_05,
        MEASURES.DIVIDENDS_D_06,
        MEASURES.WRITE_DOWNS_D_07,
        MEASURES.DEPRECIATIONS_D_08,
        MEASURES.PROVISION_D_09,
        MEASURES.RESULTAAT_VR_BELASTING_10,

        MEMBER MEASURES.x

    } ON ROWS
```

Comment: This is not going to work for me because I need to totals of every category (row). If I execute the following query I would receive only one value for one company. But I need the totals of all the measures for all the companies. So I need a total value for RESULTAATVRBELASTING, EBIDTA, FINANCIAL INCOME,... (11 values in total). But I thank you for your response!